# Select Sheet Excel when opening from IIS

Tags: excel, sharepoint, iis, impersonation

I'm trying to get this work for one week now, and i'm still lost.
So basically I have an Excel File that i Open From Sharepoint in which i want to do some changes and save again.

I'm opening it using :

```
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;
using(Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator())
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                    Missing.Value,
                    true,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value);
        }

        return excelWorkbook;
```

I think this is pretty ok for the moment. I'm using Impersonation to have rights on to open it and everything.

After that I make a copy of that so that two people can work on the same time on two different excel. But that's not the problem (well i don't think so).

```
string savedPath = ExcelHelper.saveExcelWorkbookToTemp(filename, excelWorkbook);
//Closing first Excel and reopening the new one
ExcelHelper.closeExcelWorkbook(excelWorkbook);
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbookCurrent = ExcelHelper.openExcelWorkbook(savedPath);
```

First of all, when I try to open a specific worksheet (here it is named "Paramètres), I'm getting an object called : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet {System.__ComObject}. Is it normal ? I'm using this function to open a worksheet :

```
public static Excel.Worksheet openExcelWorkSheet(Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook, string name)
{
   Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
   using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator())
   {
     //Excel.WorkSheets worksheets = excelWorkbook.Sheets;
     //worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)worksheets.get_Item(name);

     worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets["Paramètres"];
     worksheet.Select(Type.Missing);
   }
   return worksheet;
}
```

After that I try to change a cell value i get this error :

- worksheet.Cells["A1"]   'worksheet.Cells["A1"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'    dynamic {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}
  or this error, depending on the way I call the cell ... 
  Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

Do you guys have any idea how i can overcome this problem ? I don't think it's a right problem, because i'm using the admin rights to do that ...

Thanks By Advance.

PS : here is my function to modify a cell

```
    public static bool writeExcelCell(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, string cellName, string cellValue)
    {
        bool written = false;
        using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator())
        {
            try
            {
                worksheet.Cells[cellName] = cellValue;
                written = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                written = false;
            }
        }
        return written;
    }
```

EDIT : Without error :

```
worksheet.get_Range("A1").Value = "AAA";
worksheet.get_Range("A3").Value2 = "BBB";
worksheet.get_Range("A2").set_Value(Type.Missing, "test");
```

But I can't see the changes when i open it ...

Comment: Try using `get_Range()` instead of `Cells[]`.  `Cells[]` expects one or two numeric parameters - eg. `Cells[1,1]`

Comment: Hey, I tried it, 
I don't get an error anymore. But when i try to open the excel i've created I don't see the value changing. I tried different way to do this (see my edit in my post). After that I save the excel, close it, and put it in my library. 

When i go to open it there is no changes ... :(

Comment: You're sure the workbook is being saved?

Comment: I've resolved that. I was using Save before closing, and i don't know why but using saveAsCopy is working, not save. 

Thanks for your help ;)